# K-means with cosine distance

Tags: machine-learning, distance, cluster-analysis, k-means, cosine-similarity

I have to write program that cluster using k-means. I have TF-IDF and also cosine similarity that looks like that

```
1.00    0.17    0.46    0.40    0.89
0.17    1.00    0.83    0.60    0.58
0.46    0.83    1.00    0.30    0.67
0.40    0.60    0.30    1.00    0.73
0.89    0.58    0.67    0.73    1.00
```

I have the output for 2-means, it goes into two group with the first centroids: D1 and D2 because their similarity is lowest( 0.17 ) so the groups are {D1, D5} and {D2, D3, D4} but what if I had to choose 3-means? How do I then choose my start centroids?

And another thing I do not understand, I am taking my TF-IDFS that I have as follows:

```
0.2 0.4 0.8 0.0 0.2
0.0 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.2
0.8 0.0 0.2 0.4 0.4
```

and make new centroids for my groups

Group1:  T1- 0.2  T2- 0.1  T3- 0.6
Group2:  T1- 0.4  T2- 0.4(6) T3-0.2

And now what do I do to again assign my documents to new centroids? Do I have to calculate now the cosine between my centroids and documents? And whether the cos value is higher to group centroid I put it there?

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, you are mixing up things.

For k-means, **you don't need the pairwise similarity table**. It never compares two objects!

Also review the many question on k-means, in particular why it's dangerous to use other distances in k-means than squared Euclidean distance (because the *mean* may not be appropritate for other distance functions). While I believe it can be shown that under fairly usable conditions it will also work for Cosine distance, I have not yet seen a proof of **why and when it is guaranteed to converge**. The proof I know is only valid for (squared) Euclidean distance.)

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the mean may not being appropriate for other distances?

Comment: Look at the **definition of variance**, the arithmetic average is an optimal least-squares estimator of the mean. Basic statistics knowledge, should be covered in any book on estimation.

Comment: Most simply: if the mean yields 0, the cosine distance is no longer defined.

Answer (score 1):

D1 and D2 cluster because their similarity is *highest* and distance *lowest*. Not low similarity.

Your initial choice of centroids is the same as in the 2 centroid case. Right? what did you do there? You use 3 random vectors, or you pick 3 data points as the initial centroids.

Your second part doesn't make sense. You assign new docs by assigning them to the closest cluster. You can, if you like, continue the iteration from there.